# IntelliJ IDEA for multiple languages or one IDE for each?

Tags: intellij-idea

I was working with PHPStorm on some PHP projects and I liked it a lot. Now I have to find an IDE for Python and since I like PHPStorm I was looking at PyCharm and IntelliJ IDEA. I’m not sure which way to go. It seems compelling to give up PHPStorm and put both PHP and Python into IntelliJ IDEA. But I’m not very sure if it is clever to choose one IDE for multiple environments.

I'm afraid that a configuration of multiple environments inside a single IDE may overload the IDE and that the configured environments interfere with each other in unwanted or bothering ways.

On top of that IntelliJ IDEA comes with a lot of Java stuff preinstalled, which I do not need. If I have to keep the Java stuff inside the IDE the case gets even worse...

So right now I have no clue which way to go..

Can someone with experience elaborate on that please?

Comment: Personal preference. I prefer to have an IDE per language, because you can get a lot of heavy things being loaded that you don't need (that's why I initially dropped Eclipse). However, it's more expensive to take that route (although I'm on an edu license with Jetbrains atm :D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ does depend on a JRE (so does Pycharm and PHPStorm), but other than that it doesn't bring a lot of "Java stuff" with it unless you add it via the plugins. It should be sufficient to download IntelliJ Ultimate and then add the PHP and Python plugins and have the desired experience of PHPStorm and PyCharm combined.

However it may be cheaper to just purchase PyCharm instead of IntelliJ ultimate, https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html The community edition doesn't support the Pycharm plugin.